# sending data back to the main ViewController xcode

Tags: xcode, view, uiviewcontroller

I am attempting to send back data from a second view controller named "waitViewController" to the main ViewController. I am using the same method as i used to send data from the first to the second only in reverse. The problem is xcode wont allow me to use ViewController in the waitViewController.h but instead wants me to write UIViewController. How do I fix this?
What i want it to be:
[image: what i want it to be]
The errors its giving me:
[image: the errors its giving me]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be that you need to use an '@class' instead of '#import ViewController.h'

So replace that import statement with:

```
@class ViewController;
```

You need this if two classes depend on each other for their definitions, as your two view controller classes seem to do.

If you end up using an @class, you have to then import 'ViewController.h' in your implementation file. the @class prevents an infinite loop of (otherwise) co-dependent class definitions. As I understand it, @class means "this class "SomeClass" exists, so don't worry about it, even though I'm not going to import its interface just yet."

### EDIT:

By the way, I feel like I should mention that @class is a hack and there's another, more elegant solution: a (formal or informal) protocol. To use a formal protocol: put a protocol definition at the top of 'WaitViewController.h':

```
@protocol WaitControllerDelegate
 -(void) useThisNewData: (NSWhateverDataType *) theData; 
- (void) useThisOtherData:(SomeOtherDataType) otherData;
@end
```

In the WaitViewController interface, don't define 'turnData' as type 'ViewController *'. Instead define it as type "id ":

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <WaitControllerDelegate> turnDataDelegate;
```

(Note that you use 'assign' instead of 'retain' under the assumption that ViewController owns a 'retain' reference to WaitViewController and you don't want two objects that have strong references to each other--they'll create a 'retain loop', i.e. will mutually never allow each other to deallocate.)
In the WaitViewController implementation file, whenever you need to send back data, call

```
[turnDataDelegate useThisNewData: someData];
```

In ViewController.h, announce that you're adopting the 'WaitControllerDelegate' protocol:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <WaitControllerDelegate> {
```

Then, in ViewController.m implement the 'WaitControllerDelegate' methods, just like you would any other methods, but you don't have to declare them in the interface:

```
- (void) useThisNewData: (NSWhateverDataType *) theData {
   ...do whatever you want
}
```

This approach involves a little more work but is better because it allows the 'WaitViewController' class to be more self contained and, in general, in theory, makes your classes more reusable.

Comment: Worked! you are a savior!